# Can't start mysql on xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

I used xampp v3.2.1 on windows 10. I have got `Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.` problem. But `apache` is ok.

I already search a lot of answer with this problem by googling and it didn't match with my problem.

I already try to change port number to others one in `my.ini` but it didn't work.

I tried to delete all files except database folder in `c:\xampp\mysql\data`. But still getting the same error.

Here is my error log:

```
2017-03-02 11:53:53 a3c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
170302 11:53:53 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
170302 11:53:53 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170302 11:53:53 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
170302 11:53:53 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
170302 11:53:53 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
170302 11:53:53 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
170302 11:53:53 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
170302 11:53:53 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170302 11:53:53 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
170302 11:53:53 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 49463
170302 11:53:53 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
170302 11:53:53 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
170302 11:53:53 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
170302 11:53:53 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
170302 11:53:53 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 1600614
170302 11:53:53 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
170302 11:53:54 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
170302 11:53:54 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
170302 11:53:54 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.22-72.0 started; log sequence number 1600614
170302 11:53:54 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
170302 11:53:54 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Have you checked the memory allocated in my.conf?

Comment: add more log after the Server socket created on IP: '::'. line

Comment: Ooops!!! I didn't find `my.cnf` file in `xampp\mysql\data` folder. May be I delete.So, how can I do that? @AnandG

Comment: This is the the last line of the log file @Raj

Comment: it mean the server is running without binding to any ip/port

Comment: Yes, now I binding to 127.0.0.1 and now the last line of error log is like this: `170302 12:15:46 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.` . But still error @Raj

Comment: could you put the my.cfg file

Comment: Did you check mysql in services if exists and running? Maybe you have more than one mysql server beside xampp. It could result a conflict both

Comment: No, its not running in services.msc @reds

Comment: can you start it?

Answer (score 0):

Check you have this two lines in the my.ini

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
port        = 3306
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change [mysql port](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-change-the-port-of-a-MySQL-server-in-XAMPP):

```
 xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini
```